# Checking UDP port in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I'm trying to check a servers UDP port using PHP. here is my code:

```
<?php
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {}
function checkUDP($host,$port=80){
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port, $errno, $errstr,1.0);
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
}
if(checkUDP($MyIP,9)){
    echo $MyIP.' is open';
}else{
    echo $MyIP.' is closed';
}
echo '<br />';
?>
```

But I always get True result (port is open). This code works on TCP port but why I couldn't get the UDP port results?

Comment: Do you have a service running on that port already?

Comment: UDP Ports do not work in the same way as TCP Ports. Checking for open UDP ports requires that you attempt to send a packet to a specific service associated with that port, and monitor the response that is returned. Your existing method will never work.

Comment: Note that udp is a connectionless protocol, socket opening doesn't create any network trafic afaik.

Comment: I used fwrite but it took too long to response. could you write a simple code?